# Is it safe to call getters in actions in Vuex on Vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, action, getter

Can somebody explain me this use case in Vue 2?

I have two actions. The second one is called immediately after the first one. The first one set some state variables nad the second one calls getters which are based on that state variables which were set up by first action. I am not sure if the second action will have fresh data from that getters.

Hope someone understand what I mean.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "action" you mean "dispatch", then no.
An "action" is **asynchronous**, so you will have two "actions" that will attack the same resource without guaranteeing the relevance of the data.

If your first action only modifies the state, then you should use a commit which is synchronous.

Otherwise, you have to wait for the result of your first action.
An action always returns a promise so you can do something like this :

```
dispatch('firstAction', prop)
    .then(function () {
      dispatch('scdAction', prop)
    })
```

Comment: Hmm but documentation says "Actions are often asynchronous". So they should not be  async by default. Anyway, if I use await before the first action the second one should get expected value. Am I right?

Comment: > Anyway, if I use await before the first action the second one should get expected value.
Yes u'r right here.
According to the documentation, maybe actions can be sync but It is more difficult to maintain a code if some actions are synchronous and others are not. This is just my opinion but it's better to keep a similar logic in vuex even if you use awaits elsewhere

Comment: Also, prefer using `async/await` rather than `.then`.